# Взять значение из ответа XML

Tags: php

Получаю ответ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESPONSE>
<status>0</status>
<credits>366</credits>
<amount>549.7</amount>
<currency>RUR</currency>
</RESPONSE>
```

Как вывести значение которое в тегах amount?

Comment: `$myXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $myXML ->amount;`   базовое использование http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESPONSE>
        <status>0</status>
        <credits>366</credits>
        <amount>549.7</amount>
        <currency>RUR</currency>
</RESPONSE>';

$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$amount = (float) $element->amount;

var_dump($amount);
```

Выведет:

```
double(549.7)
```